# Is it possible to disable ipv6 using cloud-init?

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi, ipv6, cluster

I have a cluster of raspberry pi's and I am updating the os from raspian to ubuntu 20.04. I am able to configure a static ip address and name server, but I can not figure out how to disable ipv6. The cloud-init documentation states that dhcp6 is defaulted to false, but my system still shows an ipv6 address on boot. I am new to cloud-init and figuring things out as I go along. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the IPv6 address that you get an fe80:: link-local address?

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
write_files:
  - path: /etc/sysctl.d/10-disable-ipv6.conf
    permissions: 0644
    owner: root
    content: |
      net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
runcmd:
  - systemctl restart systemd-sysctl
```

to test it without restating:

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl`

confirm with:

`ip a`

and see there is no IPv6 address on the eth0 interface

`runcmd` is necessary to make the configuration take effect, and [is executed after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095839/cloud-init-what-is-the-execution-order-of-cloud-config-directives) the `write_files` directive.